# IOS 9.x UIWebview/WKWebview loadRequest using WIFI (hi speed internet) is slow

Tags: ios, https, uiwebview, wifi, ios9

Has anyone experienced slow connection using UIWebView or WKWebView when accessing https URL in iOS9.x using wifi connection(hi speed internet around 50MBPS)?

it doesn't happen on IOS 8 and below and also when using Mobile data.

note: the https request has a 302 response but it is still really fast in ios 8 or 7 or when I am using mobile data.

Thanks

Comment: did you see similar issue in safari at the same time?

Comment: yes it is also the same in safari

Comment: Issue is then not related to UIWebView or wkwebview. Also there is no data issue hot topics in ios9 so far, Can you check with carrier operator regarding issue in that region / can be a problem with signal strength or signal interference in your place

Comment: the weird thing is it is faster when using a mobile Data with 10MBPS than using wifi with actual 50MBPS download rate in ios9

Comment: As i see mobile data with 10Mbs is faster, so issue is with only WIFI, generally wifi speed depends(iphone is good in wifi) on the wifi router, you even see this difference in other devices as well from your wifi device, infact your hotspot from moblie must be faster in other devices.

Comment: can you remove the ios tags from the question and change contents of question, so some wifi experts can help you out in resolving the issue

Comment: no i cant do that because i know it is related to that. it perfectly works in ios 8 and 7 and even in iphone 4, but not in ios 9 iphone 6, 6s , i already submitted to apple bug about this.

Comment: sorry for my misunderstanding if you have already checked with other phones then lets wait for some expert comments.. i guess issue could be related to particular wifi communication, ignore if you already checked changing the wifi router..